# unable to update category dropdown menu in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This is my **category dropdown code** which i want to update

*in case selected value should be default value like(category or sub category name), if i don't want to choose any value then the default value should be(category or sub category name) that i given value previous, and previous value always selected. otherwise i choose another value i want and able to update*

```
<div class="control-group">
 <label class="control-label">Under Category </label>
 <div class="controls">
<select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">
<option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>

@foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
 <option value="{{$cat->id}}">
{{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->name }}

</option>
@endforeach
</select>

</div>
</div>
```

i want to data like that 
[image: pic one] 
[image: pic two]

I already trying this code:-

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Under Category </label>
    <div class="controls">
  <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">
   @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
  <option value="{{$cat->id}}">

@if{{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->name }} selected @endif{{ $cat->name }}

  </option>
     @endforeach
 </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

but I get error like this

**syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' (View: F:\laragon\www\flipcart\resources\views\admin\products\editproduct.blade.php)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need to use ternery and if both. You can use just,

```
{{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->name }}
```

If you add both there will be an error.

```
@foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
           <option value="{{$cat->id}}">
                 {{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->name }}
           </option>
@endforeach
```

BTW.

Option with selected should be like this,

```
<option selected value="{{$cat->id}}"> 
</option>
```

So you need to add condition like this I suggest,

```
<option {{ Condition ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{$cat->id}}"> 
    Text
</option>
```

Comment: ,sir, the default value always same,thats the problem.i want default value always diffenr from each other because category id is not same.

Comment: Think selected should be inside <option> tag

Comment: @TareqAhmed I changed the answer bit. Hope its more useful now

Comment: sir in case,  selected value always same in diferent id.but sir selected value always different because their id not same

Comment: How do you decide the selected value?

Comment: selected value always different, suppose i have ten categories,so when i update a category its selected value always different,but in case my selected value always same

Comment: think you can save selected value inside db column like is_selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213249/discussion-between-tareq-ahmed-and-aruna-perera).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="control-group">
           <label class="control-label">Under Category </label>
      <div class="controls">
     <select name="category_id" id="category_id" style="width:220px;">
      @foreach(App\Category::all() as $cat)
     <option @if($product->category_id==$cat->id) selected @endif value="{{$cat->id}}">
      {{ $cat->parent ? '--' . $cat->name : $cat->name }}
      </option>                                                                     
     @endforeach
        </select>

     </div>
     </div>
```